# How can i certify cabling with a cat5 certifyer if the cabling is mixed cat5 and cat6 thanks

Tags: networking, authentication, testing, cable, cat5e

Hello I'm getting ready to certify some cabling and realized it is mix matched cat5 and 6 but my certifier is only for cat5. So I wonder if I needed a speacial certifier to do that thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to ask you shouldn’t be  allowed to certify either [cat5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_5_cable) or [cat6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable).

Simple testers (for home use) only detect if all wire pairs connect and if so are wired correctly in the regard that pin 1 on one end is also pin 1 on the other end. (In that regard there is no difference between cat 5 and 6 by the way.)

Certification requires much more such as actually ***measuring*** the performance of the structured cabling and connections and subsequently generating test reports that verify if the cable length meets the standards and requirements for a certain industry standard or not.

Tooling that only supports cat5 can never be used to certify cat6 as cat6. Cat 6 needs to support higher frequencies (250 MHz compared to 100 MHz for cat 5e) and has much stricter requirements with regards to allowed crosstalk and attenuation. When your tooling can't measure that, you can only measure if a cable length meets the requirements for Cat 5.

Comment: I agree, automated tester costs really a couple thousands